# ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached when i run python manager.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43TtI.png)
when i run python manager.py makemigrations , the problem as the picture.

i check the django source code, find the problem code at here picture 2，
it can work when i note this line:self._out.write(style_func(msg)).
I don't know how make this problem.
[django source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHdE0.png)

Comment: Please type-in the error message and relevant code snippets in the question instead of posting screenshots ([Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: i got the answer. because i add sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach()) in another python file

Comment: Please edit your question properly and put the answer below and explain how did you fix it, so that it could help other people who get the same problem